# regex to match pattern followed some string

Tags: regex

I have following text. I want to capture the pattern `ddd-dd-ddd` followed by all text until I again hit a `ddd-dd-ddd`.
I am trying to use this regex

```
\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\b.*
```

it matches 982-99-122 followed by the sentence until it hits a line feed. then again the second number 586-33-453 is matched followed by the text on the same line. but it fails to capture the text that continues on the next line.

OR if I remove the line feed from this string, it will only capture the first number 982-99-122 and captures the whole string i.e. does not match the second number 586-33-453

How should I fix both these issues, 1. when line feeds are part of the string and 2. when the string does not have line feeds.

```
982-99-122 (FCC 333/22) lube oil service pump 1b discharge lube oil service pump  
aaa bb dsdsd  
586-33-453 Matches exactly 3 times 0-e single character in the range between 
dfldfldflkdf 545-66-666 sdkjsl () jdfkjd-kfdkf sdfl  
848-99-040 sdsd"" df  
dfdf
```

Comment: [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/NrwCM6/1)? Or maybe [like `\b([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3})\b([\s\S]*?)(?=\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\b|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/NrwCM6/2)?

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks for the quick answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want

```
\b([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3})\b([\s\S]*?)(?=\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\b|$)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrwCM6/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3})` - 3 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 3 digits
- `\b` - word boundary
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\b|$)?` - a positive lookahead that requires 3 diigts, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and 3 digits as a whole word or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.